# PY, JP, and HZ in Pleco dictionary

Tags: characters, dictionary

I was wondering what PY, JP, and HZ stand for in the Pleco dictionary for Android.

I think, PY probably stands for pinyin.

HZ probably stands for hanzi, but I don't understand, why sometimes HZ appears in the dictionary, and sometimes not.

JP seems found next to Cantonese, but I would like to know what it stands for. I thought Wade-Guiles notation was the standard notation for Cantonese (correct me if I'm wrong), but perhaps not.

Thanks.

I was also wondering why HZ appears, for instance, in the entry for zhu (箸)，but not in the entry for kuai (筷).

Thanks.

[image: zhu4 Pleco entry]

[image: Pleco entry for kuai 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JP = Jyutping(粤拼) means Cantonese Pinyin, developed by the Linguistic Society of Hong Kong. There really isn't an official romanisation of Cantonese, since it self is a dialect, therefore hard to make official representation, though Jyutping is probably the most widely used one at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also write to me that Jyut syllable in IPA. This Cantonese syllable does not seem to resemble any of the Mandarin syllables and I would like to know how the J and the y and the ut are pronounced. How to pronounce these? Thanks.